# Deploying data to the JFrog artifactory from Java SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, artifactory

I am developing a SpringBoot application that generates some binary data blob.
I can write it to a file, but per my requirements this data shall be stored in the JFrog artifactory in the specified directory with the particular name.

I spent couple days studying JFrog REST API documentation, but it only provides CURL and CLI interfaces without much of details. It does describe few headers, but it is quite unclear what are request params, body, etc, what would be possible return codes and responses.

I did find here post regarding downloads from the artifactory:
[How to connect and download artifacts from JFrog Artifactory in a Spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73024804/how-to-connect-and-download-artifacts-from-jfrog-artifactory-in-a-spring-boot-ap/73033720#73033720)
I did test it for download and it is working. Using it as example I created my own function to do upload (deployment):

```
    OperationStatus doUpload(String filePath, String folder, String name) 
        throws MalformedURLException, ProtocolException, IOException {
    StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder(this.getBaseUrl()).append('/')
            .append(this.target);
    if(folder != null) {
        pathBuilder.append('/').append(folder);
    }
    pathBuilder.append('/').append(name);
    URL repositoryUrl = new URL(pathBuilder.toString());
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) repositoryUrl.openConnection();
    connection.addRequestProperty(ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN_HEADER_NAME, token);
    connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
        try (FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath))) {
            int b;
            while((b = input.read()) != -1) {
                output.write(b);
            }
        }
        output.flush();
    }
    connection.connect();
    return new OperationStatus("success", "Artifact " + name + " deployed");
}
```

Function works without errors, but artifact does not appear in the artifactory. If someone can point out what I am doing wrong, I will appreciate it.

Comment: which kind of client you are using to consume or deploy these files? What are the files which you produce? Are you using Maven or Gradle? What's wrong with curl?

Comment: I am using Maven. I am creating a REST service that is in its own turn calling other APIs to get data, combine them into a tarball and deploy to the artifactory. Nothing is wrong with curl for someone who is writing a shell script, but I am writing a Java service and JFrog documentation of their REST API is horrible. That is why I am asking question here.

Comment: In order to debug it I suggest checking the artifactory-request.log, perhaps the request doesn't reach Artifactory correctly.
For example the PUT request should look like "https://your-artifactory-url/artifactory/repo-name/path/to/file.jar"

Comment: Sorry, but you are quoting JFrog documentation, which is a) useless, b) incorrect.